# String not printing using std::cout

Tags: c++

When trying the print the contents of the `readdata` string the result is not as expected, however if I individually print out the contents of 'line' the correct result is printed:

```
std::string line;
std::string readdata;
std::ifstream file(filename);
if (file.is_open()) 
{
    for (int i=0;std::getline(file,line) && i<10;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<line<<std::endl;    //Prints correct result for each instance.
        readdata.append(line); 
        if (i!=9)
        {
            readdata.append(" ");
        }

    }
    std::cout<<readdata<<std::endl;    //Prints garbled result.
    file.close();   
}
```

The text file being read contains this data:

```
#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
8%203:
,1$&
!-*%
.#7&33&
#*#71%
&-&641'2
#))85
9&330*
```

The printing of 'line' prints this, but when `readdata` is printed the result is:

```
9&330*'2
```

Comment: Does the file have any '\r' characters that may be causing it to carriage return and overwrite on output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are getting a `'\r'` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

```
    readdata.append(line.substr(0, line.find("\r")));
```